# Javascript crossdomain widget

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I want to create javascript widget similar to linkedin Member profile. https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/member-profile-plugin?button-type-inline=true

On my site the user can manage some data. 
I want to allow for user to copy some HTML code and insert in his site HTML to display the data.

I want HTML code looks like:

```
<script src="http://mysite.com/code.js?userid=123"></script>
```

And if user inserts this code in his site then javascript code is loaded and data are displayed (widget displayed)

How to do this? I know about crossdomain restrictions. But in case of linkedin this is not the problem. Their widget works fine.

Thanks.

UPDATE.
As i understand from comments, it is not the problem to display any data in page that includes my javascript file. I am going to do tests.

Comment: Just code it ***! But seriously, if a user embeds your script, it works, if you want the script to load external data, use JSONP. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the data is embedded inside the script, or it is loaded via [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)